# Changing HTML Form Text Using Javascript and/or Razor

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net, razor

I'm working in a view that deals with creating account information and resetting passwords. **Where I'm stuck: depending if the password request was sent, approved, or denied, this will in turn change how the log in screen/password request appears.**  I want it to change the present text in the form and update it with a message and the user can submit OK, etc. so the browser will close automatically (or have the current form be hidden so I can create a new one with the information, whichever is easier).

Before I had an alert to send the message, but now I need it as HTML to style it.

```
//All of this is in a Javascript script tag

var reset = getParameterByName('reset');

if (reset == "sent") {
//alert("Done! Please check your email to confirm.")

//How can I change the current text on the form?
document.getElementsByClassName('panel-login').innerHTML = "<div class='panel-login' style='color: white; background-color: blue;'><p>Done! Please check your email to confirm.</p></div>";

    //Here so I know something is updating on the site...
    var message = "<div style='color: white; background-color: blue;'><p>Done! Please check your email to confirm.</p></div>";
    document.write(message);  
}

if (reset == "fail") {
    alert("Password reset request failed.")
}

if (reset == "approved") {
    alert("Confirmed! A password reset email has been issued.")
    @*var url = '@Url.Action("Login", "Account")';
    window.location = url;*@
}
```

(Whatever works with the first if (sent) will be copied and pasted into the last two once I get this working.)

This is the HTML for the above:

```
<div class="panel_login" style="opacity: 0.9;">
<div class="">
    @using (Html.BeginForm("ResetPassword2", "Account", new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }, FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-signin mg-btm" }))
    {
        <div class="" style="padding-left: 20px; padding-right: 20px; padding-bottom: 20px; padding-top: 10px; ">
            <div class="">
                @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "Password reset was unsuccessful. Please check email and try again.")
                <label>Email</label>
                <div class="input-group">
                    <span id="emailinput" ng-model="user.EMAIL" class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span></span>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Email)
                </div>

            </div>

        </div><div class="panel-footer">
            <div class="row centered">
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <button id="singlebutton" name="singlebutton" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="Back(); return false;">Cancel</button>
                    <button class="btn btn-large btn-danger" type="submit" ng-click="resetpassword(user)">Request Password Reset</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

I've tried hiding the `panel-login` so I can create a new div/element to display the message/form.  It didn't work (doing something wrong):

```
document.getElementsbyClassName('panel-login').style.display = 'none';
```

Learned that since it was an array, I will need something else since the above produces a null and error. Tried using a variable to get the class and then a for statement to target it to style.  Again, no avail.

I'm not familiar with Razor (still learning) and copying what I need in JavaScript seems to just replicate things instead of changing what's already there.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up figuring this out.

Essentially, I created other divs which is styled similarly to the log in screen and in the same position, but kept them hidden until they're called by their function to appear depending on user input and URL.  Log in screen originally is visible but later hidden when another div is made visible to display the tailored message.

I first created this through Javascript (using functions to create HTML), but later changed it to HTML and CSS but still used JS to call the functions.  The main reason I had to switch is because some messages after being confirmed either submitted something or was supposed to close the tab or go back and I had trouble doing so since apparently a script can't close the current page that didn't initially open it.  Still having that problem in Chrome TBH.

Answer (score 0):

If I follow you, `getElementsByClassName` is the culprit. Try:

```
var loginPanel = document.getElementsbyClassName('panel-login')[0];
```

This will find the first match in the array.

Comment: True.  Though I've tried this (sorry that I wasn't clear but I stated so in the second to last paragraph) and I wasn't able to use that to hide that class.  I tried adding ids to them and was able to have them hidden.  Now I'm confused about adding a message.  I think instead of adding things, I will make the whole form hidden and just add a separate div for a message. Thanks for the answer!